Individual Email Result not showned for specific profile users
I have a problem with the "Individual Email Results" box , in the Related tab of the Accounts (Contact) , when i login to Salesforce with users that haves a specific PROFILE (Profile1).
With other users that haves different profiles (es. Profile2) i navigate to a Contact, then to Related tab/list , and i can see correctly the "Individual Email Results" box.
With an User that is in Profile1 the "Individual Email Results" box IS NOT SHOWNED.
I want to see this box also for users in PROFILE1.
I have tried to see the differences between these 2 profiles , and set the same property/flag, but i have not resolved.
In Profile I have tried to

Enable READ to "Individual Email Results" to Customized Object Auth
...

and other flags...
Can you explain what I must set in profile, or in other settings, to enable show of Individual Email Results" tho these Users that are in Profile1?
Thank you


